# As I move my sprite around it keeps going off the window

Tags: c++, window, game-engine, sfml

I currently am using SFML with c++ and am having a small issue keeping my sprite on the page.  Below is the code and if anyone has any ideas that could help fix my issue that would be amazing!

```
     if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down) && shape1.getPosition().y < screenLength)
        {   
                if (shape1.getGlobalBounds().intersects( line1.getGlobalBounds()) || shape1.getGlobalBounds().intersects(line.getGlobalBounds()) || shape1.getGlobalBounds().intersects(line2.getGlobalBounds()))
                {
                    shape1.move(0.0f, -.2f);                    
                    std::cout << "Collision";
                }
```

As I keep pushing the down button it lets me travel off the bottom of the generated window instead of skipping it like it should based on my if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue and got it fixed... so when I take the

```
 shape1.globalBounds().x
```

it returns the X of the top of the sprite. So I had to put this line it to make it work correctly:

```
float test = shape1.getGlobalBounds().top +  shape1.getGlobalBounds().height;
```

Now it stops on the screenLength and will keep working if the screen size and etc. is adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Your test is "y < screenLength", but you decrease your value when you call move.
Log your y, and maybe your solution is something like "if y >= 0".

Comment: So I did that and apparently my if() statement works how it is but it appears that the windowLength goes slightly further then the window actually displays? Which is weird.